# How can I clear the map with every search?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I have a real-time fleet Google map with basic marks and AJAX. My query (PHP) has filter for bus numbers (12031) and route (A11). When I do the search the first time it works perfectly and shows me the marks, but when I do a second search the old marks stay in the map. How can I clear the map with every search?

The map:

http://190.216.202.35/busestr/pruebabuses.php

The AJAX:

```
    function ajax(){    //When the Window finishes loading...
var dire;

//$('#ruta').on("focus", function(){
var value=$.trim($("#ruta").val());
if(value.length>0)
{

dire = "marks.php?ruta="+ruta;

}
var value=$.trim($("#bus").val());
if(value.length>0)
{
dire = "marks.php?bus="+bus;
}



  $.ajax({                
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          // data: {name:'A21'},
          url: dire,                  
          //cache: true,
          success: function setmap(data){

                  for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
                    //  console.log (data[i].BUSNUMBER)

    // console.log (data);
    data[i].GPSX = data[i].GPSX.replace("-76","-76.");
        data[i].GPSY = data[i].GPSY.replace("3","3.");  
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].GPSY, data[i].GPSX);
// console.log (myLatLng);
        if (markerarray[data[i].BUSNUMBER] && markerarray[data[i].BUSNUMBER].setPosition){
          markerarray[data[i].BUSNUMBER].setPosition(myLatLng)}
        else {
          marker[i] =  new MarkerWithLabel({
            map:map,
            //labelClass: "mylabels",
            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
            labelContent: '<div>'+ data[i].BUSNUMBER+'<br>'+data[i].LINEA+'</div>',
            //icon:{
              //some options here
            //}
          });
          markerarray[data[i].BUSNUMBER] = marker[i];
          marker[i].setPosition(myLatLng);
        markers.push(marker[i])



        }}}
        });


    }
```

The buttons:

```
       $("#Botbuscar").click(function() {
     ruta = document.getElementById("ruta").value;
      if (marker.length == 0){var casa = setInterval(ajax,2000);}
      else  (clearInterval(casa), clearMarkers())


     $("#Botbuscar").val("");
     return false; 

  });
    $("#Botbuscar").click(function() {
     bus = document.getElementById("bus").value;
      if (marker.length == 0){var casa = setInterval(ajax,2000);}
      else  (clearInterval(casa), clearMarkers())
     $("#Botbuscar").val("");
     return false; 

  });



    function setAllMap(map) {
     for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++ ) {
        marker[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }


    function clearMarkers() {
      setAllMap(null);
    }
```

The inputs

```
 <form >
Ruta:<input type="text" id="ruta" /><br/>
Bus:<input type="text" id="bus" />
<button id="Botbuscar" >Buscar</button>
</form>
```

**Update**

Accomplish clear the map changing the input search, but first the user must clear de field (extra issue) but when i want make a new search many markers remain in the map how a can fix that?

Comment: Have you tried the [**setAllMap(null)**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) function? Or you can remove individual markers, too. When user does a new search, do a marker.remove() on your old markers, perhaps? The above link has more details on removing markers.

Comment: @so_jin_ee yes i use the function but no clean the marks every time only the first time

Comment: How are you keeping track of your old markers. Your marker array's scope should be correct in order for your remove() method to access newly added markers. I suggest you check all your markers (maybe do a log right before your new search?) once after you add them on the map.

Comment: The markers dont change only their position, you say save the marks?

Comment: Where are you setting markers to null? or setting `setAllMap(null)`?

Comment: i remove the function is no working for me but i can put it @Craicerjack

Comment: You should really put it in. If the problem is about removing markers and you dont include the code for removing your markers...

Comment: Is include, but still no work

Comment: I mean include it in the code in your question above.

Comment: And how do you trigger  `clearMarkers()`

Comment: @Craicerjack there is everytingh

Comment: Is  `clearMarkers()` being fired? Can you put a `console.log` or an `alert` within  `clearMarkers()` to test if it is being called.

Comment: @Craicerjack how i can call the function if is inside the ajax ?¿ is get an error

Comment: `function clearMarkers() {
  alert('fired');setAllMap(null);
}` <-- do this and then see if your button 'delete markers' triggers the alert

Comment: @Craicerjack is fired the function but no clear the map every time and stop the process

Comment: Is markerarray an object or an array? you should clear that too within `clearMarkers()`. `markerarray = []`. Other than that I dont know - the google tutorial is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

Comment: @Craicerjack Markerarray is an array and now change the code but still without working but tnks

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you give I can't see any control to test, but for the code you gave I think the problem is with `for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){` you are editing only a subset of marks, so the marks that are greater than data.lenght are left as they were before the second call.

Comment: in the left bottom are the inputs